# How to escape a sup tag in xpath selector

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the text content from the below HTML tag, but the  `<sup>` tag is preventing me from getting the desired text.

The text I want to extract is simply  `(4:6, 6:7)`. how can I extract this text at the same time escaping the `<sup>` tag.

I tried this `"//p/text()"`, but I am only getting the part before the `<sup>` tag `(4:6, 6`

**my html tag**

`'<p class="result"><span class="bold">Final result </span><strong>0:2</strong> (4:6, 6<sup>5</sup>:7)</p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the only text that is a direct text of `p`, the rest are texts inside a child tag.

```py
scrapy shell file:///path/to/file.html

In [1]: ''.join(response.xpath('//p[@class="result"]/text()').getall())
Out[1]: ' (4:6, 6:7)'
```